# jQuery .change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does the output not change when I change the input?

### HTML

```
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in"></input>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#in').on("change", function(){
    $('#out').html($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahpu8wwx/2/

Comment: You have to add jQuery, check this, http://jsfiddle.net/ahpu8wwx/3/

Comment: you have error jquery is not included. that is why $ is not defined. look into console you will something like this `$ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery library in your fiddle. Use **[`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** or **[`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)** event for instant update. **[`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)** event only fires when you are focus out from input field

```js
$('#in').on("input", function(){
    $('#out').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works, make sure you have included jQuery.
[image]